# Representing nilpotent lie algebras and nilpotent elements

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let L be a nilpotent lie algebra of finite dimension over $\mathbb{C}$. And consider a representation $\rho: L\to gl_n(\mathbb{C})$. Is $\rho(x)$ nilpotent as a matrix for all $x\in L$?

Comment: It is "Lie" algebra (after Sophus Lie), not "lie" algebra. Did you try an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\varphi \left(\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is a Lie homomorphism of abelian one-dimensional Lie algebras, and the image is not nilpotent as a matrix.

Things change for the adjoint representation, but that has to be proven.